# Switch from one git branch to another without loosing the newly added code

Tags: git, gitlab, git-branch, git-commit, git-checkout

I have a repository having two branches master ( keeps final error free code ) and develop ( developing branch ).The default branch is master, I cloned and worked on the project, but unfortunately I forgot to checkout to the develop branch before I start coding.So all the changes that I made will be on the master branch. Is there any way to switch the branch after developing? so that I can commit and push the code only to the develop branch without loosing my code.

Comment: Just do `git branch new-branch` to create a new branch at your current HEAD and then reset the `master` back to where you want it. (eg, `git branch new-branch; git reset --hard @{u}; git checkout new-branch`)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any work saved on your develop branch, just delete it with `git branch -d develop` and rename master to develop with `git branch -m master develop`.

If you have something already on your develop, just merge the changes into develop with `git checkout develop` then `git merge master`.

Answer (score -1):

```
git fetch origin master
git checkout main
```

this command will switch your branch